# Setting up IDT in long mode

Tags: kernel, x86-64, interrupt-handling

I am writing a kernel and as an assembly project, I am writing the whole thing in assembly (specifically intel).  I have searched the internet trying to find info on what an IDT should look like in long mode, but I haven't really found a concise explanation.  Are there any places I could look to help me make more sense of this whole IDT.
Since I would like to figure this out, please do not spoon feed me answers about how to set up an IDT.

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table . 64-bit IDT is similar to the 32-bit one except the IDT entries have been widened from 8 bytes to 16-bytes each. That link shows the differences. The base in the IDTR record has also been expanded from 32-bits to 64-bits. The Intel manuals have everything you need to know

Comment: How is it possible that you are not aware of the [Intel Manual 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html) when you don't like to be spoon fed? That's the only source needed to (and must) be consulted when implementing an OS from scratch without copy-pasting tutorial code.

Comment: Because I have never done this before haha.  I truly am a newbie.  Thanks for the pointer.  Cheers, mate!